# How to convert webP image format to normal ? php

Tags: php, image, webp

I have an ios and android application. sometime the users upload webP image to my server. the problem is ios can't show this image when it's downloaded from my server.

so I want to check within my php code. if the image is webP format . then i will convert it to png format.

How could i do that using php?

Comment: imagemagick can handle webp image format...

Comment: @JuniusRendel thank you for your response. could you please write your suggested code. answer .

Comment: you should also take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/using) they explain how to convert to png in a single command line with their `libwebp` library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using [libwebp](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/using):**
( I assume `$file` is an absolute path and `libwebp` is installed)

```
$regex="/^(.*)(\.webp)$/";
if(preg_match($regex, $file)){
   $out=preg_replace($regex, "${1}.png", $file);
   exec("dwebp $file -o $out");
}
```

Didn't test, but should work...

Comment: do not assume webhosts have exec() enabled

Answer (score 24):

It's late but just for the sake of it. It can be done using PHP only. Without any external tool.

Quoted from PHP.net [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromwebp.php):

```
<?php
// Load the WebP file
$im = imagecreatefromwebp('./example.webp');

// Convert it to a jpeg file with 100% quality
imagejpeg($im, './example.jpeg', 100);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

So I assume you can use `imagepng()` instead of imagejpeg that is in the example.